# The idea for game arrange images block

Tags: java, c#-4.0

Could someone tell me the idea or flow of building the game arrange images block to done picture. How to split images into small ones and control it?(java or c#)

Comment: "building the game arrange images block to done picture" - If you want help, you're going to need to rephrase your wording to make it clear.

Comment: Sorry, i don't known name in english of this game.there is a picture it can be split into 4, 9, 16 parts with random arangements. I want to known how to split this piture and control it in c# or java

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of a Sliding Block puzzle? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliding_puzzle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you're using Java

First, load the completed image of the Sliding Block puzzle into memory.  This is easily accomplished with the read method of the ImageIO class

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

String directory = "someFolder\myImage.png";
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(directory);
```

Now let's split that image up into the subpieces.  A convenient method you can use is the "getSubimage(x, y, w, h)" method of the BufferedImage class.

```
int rows = 3, cols = 3;
BufferedImage[][] pieces = new BufferedImage[rows][cols];

int imageWidth = image.getWidth();
int imageHeight = image.getHeight();
int pieceWidth = imageWidth/cols;
int pieceHeight = imageHeight/rows;

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        pieces[i][j] = image.getSubimage(j*pieceWidth, i*pieceHeight, pieceWidth, pieceHeight);
    }
}
```

Now, `pieces[i][j]` represents the subimage that is currently located at the ith row, jth col.  So let's say you want the piece in the second row, third column, this would be `pieces[1][2]`.

To swap the position of two subimages, we must swap the references in the pieces 2D array.

```
//  Swaps the subimage at row1,col1 with the subimage at row2,col2
private void swapPosition(row1, col1, row2, col2)
{
    BufferedImage temp = pieces[row1][col1];
    pieces[row1][col1] = pieces[row2][col2];
    pieces[row2][col2] = temp;
}
```

Sliding puzzles only allow you to swap adjacent pieces, so you'll probably want to add that logic into the swapPosition method.

I hope this gets you started.